# How does ASP Classic FOR EACH loop work

Tags: asp-classic, vb6, foreach, enumerators

I would like to now how the *ASP Classic/VB6* **FOR EACH** loop works.  I know with .NET IEnumberable/IEnumerator are involved, but how does VB6/ASP Classic do it?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW thanks for this, a real nostalgia trip.  http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-75539.html Was I really discussing this sort of stuff over 10 years ago, yikes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does it in a very similar way.  A class that supports foreach has a method that has the DispID of -4 which returns an enumerator object similar to an implementation of IEnumerator.

If you intend to implement this in VB6 then whilst it is possible you will have to be prepared to jump through prohibitively complicated hoops, especially since such insanely complicated stuff is now well past its sell by date.  The COM equivalent to IEnumerator is `stole.IEnumVARIANT`, one characteristic that makes it incompatible with a simple implementation in VB6 is that its `Next` method uses `S_FALSE` HResult.

If you really, really want to do this then get this book: [Advanced Visual Basic 6](http://powervb.com/) if you can.   **Warning** from a typical VB6 developers point of view the term "Advanced" doesn't really do it justice.  "Insanely deep VB6" would be a better description.

Comment: +1 but isn't it worth mentioning the easy way to implement this in VB6: just use a Collection object?

Comment: @MarkJ:  True you could add to your object that represents some collection of things a property that returns a Collection containing a copy of the set of things your object contains.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, thanks for your answer.  Very helpful.  Glad you enjoyed the question.  Based on what you said I decided to take the easier route.  I built a simple Active Record class which is exposed via simple Interface.  The interface exposes itself via COM.  Example members include: EOF, MoveNext, MoveFirst, Fields etc.